# Strange letter when passing character through a pipe

Tags: c, file, io, pipe, system-calls

I've an input file whose content is `abcefghz`. I want to use a pipe so that a child process p1 sends 1-letter per time to his parent process which will converts this string using the ASCII code+1 (`abcefghz` will become `cdfghi{`). This new string will be send through another pipe to another child process which will print the result on an output file.

This is the code:

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
{  
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    int inputFile, outputFile;
    char stringaDalFile[256];
    char successivo;
    char stringaRisultato[256];
    int fd1[2], fd2[2]; // Pipe



    inputFile = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    outputFile = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) { 

        while ( (nread=read(inputFile, stringaDalFile, 1)) > 0) {
            close(fd1[0]);
            write(fd1[1], stringaDalFile, 1);
        }

        close(inputFile);
    }
    else { 
        close(fd1[1]);
        while ( read(fd1[0], stringaDalFile, 1) > 0 ) {

            successivo = converti(stringaDalFile[0]);

            write(fd2[1], &successivo, 1);
        }
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) { 

        close(fd2[1]);

        if (read(fd2[0], stringaRisultato, 1) == -1) {
            perror("Errore");
            exit(1);
        } 
        else {
            while ( read(fd2[0], stringaRisultato, 1) > 0 ) {
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, stringaRisultato, strlen(stringaRisultato)); //dbg
write(outputFile, stringaRisultato, strlen(stringaRisultato));
            }
        }

        close(outputFile);

        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}

char converti (char carattere) 
{
    return carattere+1;
}
```

Unfortunately, this seems to not work at 100%, the string is converted but the program enters what seems an infinite loop:

[image: string is converted but infinite loop]

If I `CTRL-C` and `gedit file2.txt`, this is its content:

[image: stranger character].

How do I fix this?

Comment: You never initialize `stringaDalFile` to any value, so it's never a proper `'\0'`-terminated string.

Comment: How might I fix?

Comment: it seemy you're using `stringaDalFile[0]` only so it doesn't have to be NUL-terminated. But it doesn't have to be an array of size 256 either, 1 should be enugh.

Comment: But concening wour problem: it's strange that you write the converted data into the pipe before even staring p2. For a larger amount of data that wouldn't work. And you don't close the write side of the pipe in the parent, so p2 will never get EOF but infinitely wait for more data

Comment: btw: you use `strlen(stringaRisultato)`. That **is** wrong if yo're not teminating the buffer. But like in the other loops you could replace `strlen()` by 1 if you're reading only one byte at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code:

1. The *real* problem, here:

   ```
   write(outputFile, stringaRisultato, strlen(stringaRisultato));
   ```

   you're using `strlen(stringaRisultato)` when `stringaRisultato` only has one valid character at the beginning and no NUL-terminator after it. Just use `1` instead.
2. You are only reading one character at a time, you don't need a string of 256 characters. Change `stringaDalFile` and `stringaRisultato` into two single `char` variables: `carattereDalFile` and `carattereRisultante`.
3. In the first child (inside `if (pid1 == 0)`) you are doing `close(fd1[0])` in a loop. You should move it out of the `while`.
4. Again in the first child, you're not doing `exit(0)`. This is what causes your program to keep running.
5. This line inside the second child:

   ```
   if (read(fd2[0], stringaRisultato, 1) == -1) {
   ```

   is only useful if you want to skip the first character. Is that intended? If not, remove that `if` and only use the `while (read(...) > 0)`.
6. You are writing everything to the pipe `fd2[1]` before starting the second child (that will read from it). If the input file is too large (some KB) this will result in filling the pipe internal buffer and will block your program on the next `write()` that it tries to perform, making it never end. To fix this, you should start the two child processes together. This would require changing the structure and logic of the code, but it's doable.

   Since I don't think that's the real problem here and this program is most probably written for educational purposes I'll leave that to you and fix the rest of the above points.

---

Working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

char converti (char carattere);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    int inputFile, outputFile;
    char carattereDalFile, carattereRisultante, successivo; // renamed
    int fd1[2], fd2[2];

    inputFile = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    outputFile = open(argv[2], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);

    pipe(fd1);
    pipe(fd2);

    pid1 = fork();
    if (pid1 == 0) {
        close(fd1[0]); // <==  moved out of the while loop

        while (read(inputFile, &carattereDalFile, 1) > 0) {
            write(fd1[1], &carattereDalFile, 1);
        }

        close(inputFile);
        exit(0); // <== added
    } else {
        close(fd1[1]);

        while (read(fd1[0], &carattereDalFile, 1) > 0) {
            successivo = converti(carattereDalFile);
            write(fd2[1], &successivo, 1);
        }
    }

    pid2 = fork();
    if (pid2 == 0) {
        close(fd2[1]);

        if (read(fd2[0], &carattereRisultante, 1) == -1) {
            perror("Errore");
            exit(1);
        } else {
            while (read(fd2[0], &carattereRisultante, 1) > 0) {
                write(outputFile, &carattereRisultante, 1);
            }
        }

        close(outputFile);
        exit(0);
    }

    return 0;
}

char converti (char carattere)
{
    return carattere+1;
}
```

Comment: There would still be a pipe buffer overflow, probably causing the parent to block in `write()` if the input file became too large because all converted data is wrtten to the pipe before the second child is even started

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt there is no such thing as "pipe buffer overflow". A pipe buffer cannot overflow. When it becomes full, following `write()`s will block until something is `read()` from the other side. This is of course a problem in OP's code, but the solution is quite complicated. OP's program is most probably written only to make some experience with pipes and `fork()`. As long as the input file is under a few KB of size (which I assume to be true) everything works.

Comment: In fact a solution is quite easy. First start both child processes and then so the read/write loop in the parent. Of couse 'pipe buffer overflow' wasn't the right wording but you've got what I meant anyway.

Comment: Grazie Marco, sei stato gentilissimo. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

`read` returns the number of byte read in so you should use that to add the NUL terminating character to the string it's populated like this

```
while ( (bytesread = read(inputFile, stringaDalFile, 1)) > 0) {
   stringaDalFile[bytesread] = '\0';
....
```

Comment: not necessary if you are only reading and writing one byte at a time. There's no stdio involved

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt they're passing the string to `strlen` so it needs to be NUL terminated - not sure what stdio has to do with anything

Comment: `stlen()` is never called for `stringaDalFile`, only for `stringaRisultato` (and there it is a bug, of course. Any yes, 'stdio' was wrong. I meant 'srinng handling'